# How to remap keys on win10 for single user

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm working in Windows 10 server with multiuser and trying to find a way to switch <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. I tried different methods but they either work for all users (Registry) or unstable (AutoHotkey).

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods of solving this issue but the easiest and the most amicable way is to use a free utility software named [Sharpkeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases/).

> SharpKeys is a utility that manages a Registry key that allows Windows to remap one key to any other key.

After downloading the software from Github you can fire it and use the software to navigate and remap the keys as your desired way and you can also disable any key as your preference.

Don't forget to hit the "write to registry" after each time of remapping a key.

[image: Sharpkeys example image]

There are also registry hacks but I don't recommend to go to the hard methods cause they can cause harm and unnecessary time for a user.

Comment: **Things that SharpKeys will not do:** Support multiple mappings for different users - the Windows key being tweaked is for an entire machine. See [here](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys#things-that-sharpkeys-will-not-do)